# Align a child class vertically to parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a webpage in which a user can show the larger image or preview of every thumbnails by hovering it.

I am using this Jquery code to show and center the larger image on the screen responsively.

```
var timer;
$(".theme-preview").hover(function() {
    var self = $(this);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      timer = false;

      $(self).children('.popup-preview').fadeIn("slow");

      $(self).children('.popup-preview').css("position", "fixed");
      $(self).children('.popup-preview').css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - ($(self).children('.popup-preview').outerHeight() / 2));
      $(self).children('.popup-preview').css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - ($(self).children('.popup-preview').outerWidth() / 2));

    }, 800);

    //return false;
  },
  function() {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = false;
    } else {
      $(this).children('.popup-preview').fadeOut("fast");
    }

    //return false;
  }
);
```

How can I align the larger image vertically the same with the parent class?

[image: Demo here]

[Here is my working sample code.](https://jsfiddle.net/pbq5ujcp/1/)

Update: Example is when the thumbnail is on the top or bottom of the screen and was hovered. The larger image should display vertically center of the screen.

[image: Should display visibly on the screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I align the larger image vertically the same with the parent class?

Use `getBoundingClientRect()` function to get the current boundary of `theme-preview` div. Then calculate the respective left and top.

```
var currentRect = self[0].getBoundingClientRect();

...

var previewPopup = self.children('.popup-preview');
      previewPopup.fadeIn("slow");

      previewPopup
        .css("position", "fixed")
        .css("top", currentRect.top - 20)
        .css("left", ( currentRect.left + (self[0].clientWidth/2)) - (self.children('.popup-preview').outerWidth() / 2));
```

[jsFiddle v1](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/pbq5ujcp/37/)

---

Updated. This should center it according to parent width and height.
[jsFiddle v2](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/pbq5ujcp/46/)

```
previewPopup
        .css("position", "fixed")
        .css("top", currentRect.top + ((self[0].clientHeight/2) - (self.children('.popup-preview').outerHeight() / 2)))
        .css("left", ( currentRect.left + (self[0].clientWidth/2)) - (self.children('.popup-preview').outerWidth() / 2));
```

Comment: This is so close to what I want to achieve. But there is one thing it lacks. Example is when the thumbnail is on the top or bottom of the screen and was hovered. The larger image should display vertically center of the screen. https://jsfiddle.net/pbq5ujcp/44/

Comment: I will accept this as an answer to my issue because it is the closest to what I want to achieve. I just need to add `.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - ($(self).children('.popup-preview').outerHeight() / 2))`  for the centering vertically see: https://jsfiddle.net/pbq5ujcp/45/

Comment: ohh.. i didnt know you want to center based on height too. based on your sketch it seems to be few-pixels-away from top :)

Comment: ok.. my bad for not reading your update. your center screen solution should work fine :)

Comment: I think `.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - ($(self).children('.popup-preview').outerHeight() / 2))` is better than `.css("top", currentRect.top + ((self[0].clientHeight/2) - (self.children('.popup-preview').outerHeight() / 2)))` when centering it to the window/screen.

Answer (score 2):

Jus make your .popup-preview 'absolute' 
and left: 0; top: 50%; and add transform: translateY(-50%);

```js
var timer;
  $(".theme-preview").hover(function() {
      var self = $(this);
    
      timer = setTimeout(function(){
        timer = false;
        
        $(self).children('.popup-preview').fadeIn("slow");
      
        $(self).children('.popup-preview').css("position","absolute");
        $(self).children('.popup-preview').css("left","0");
        $(self).children('.popup-preview').css("top","50%");
      }, 800);

      //return false;
    }, 
    function () {
      if(timer){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = false;
      }else{   
          $(this).children('.popup-preview').fadeOut("fast");
      }

      //return false;
    }
  );
```

```css
.popup-preview{
  background: black;
 position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 z-index: 1;
 display: none; 
}

.col-md-6{
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.theme-preview {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-6.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-6.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-4.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-4.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-3.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-3.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-5.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-5.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem here is when I have other thumbnails, the larger image is on top because of top:0. Should be centered vertically on the screen.

Comment: Have a look at it now and let me know if this is what you were looking for.. :)

Comment: Very good answer using css style. I will upvote your answer but @SudarpoChong answer really works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just try changing the postion to absolute

```
        var timer;
        $(".theme-preview").hover(function() {
                var self = $(this);

                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    timer = false;

                    $(self).children('.popup-preview').fadeIn("slow");

                    $(self).children('.popup-preview').css("position","absolute");
                    $(self).children('.popup-preview').css("top", '0');
                    $(self).children('.popup-preview').css("left", 'auto');

                }, 800);

                //return false;
            }, 
            function () {
                if(timer){
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = false;
                }else{          
                        $(this).children('.popup-preview').fadeOut("fast");
                }

                //return false;
            }
        );
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbq5ujcp/10/)

Comment: Should cover the thumbnail.

Comment: please check now

Comment: Problem here is when I have other thumbnails, the larger image is on top because of `top:0`. Should be centered  vertically on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timer;
$(".theme-preview").hover(function() {
    var self = $(this);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      timer = false;

      $(self).children('.popup-preview').fadeIn("slow");


    }, 800);

    //return false;
  },
  function() {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = false;
    } else {
      $(this).children('.popup-preview').fadeOut("fast");
    }

    //return false;
  }
);
```

```css
.popup-preview {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.col-md-6 {
  float: left;
}

.theme-preview {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-6.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-6.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-4.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-4.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-3.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-3.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-5.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-5.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but problem here would be all of the large image is not vertically centered.